# Setting max_execution_time for PHP7 and Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I followed [this guide](https://notes.luxian.ro/node/7) and updated the values:

`/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and change/add this:

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

and `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` as well and change/add this:

```
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 300
```

and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`, and in the cgi section add:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
```

... followed by restarts but still:

```
# php -i | grep max_execution_time
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
```

This is the location block for my site:

```
location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.*)$;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you run `php -i` from command line, it will use configuration settings for your PHP CLI client, which are likely located in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`.

If you want to check settings for your PHP-FPM, create a script with following contents in your web root:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And then go to the script URL in your browser.

Another alternative that might work is to run `php -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -i`, which will make the PHP CLI connect to your FastCGI server to execute the command. You might need to change the address depending on your configuration.

Comment: As a side note... This answer uses debian/ubuntu-ish paths to reflect the question (i believe). Yours may likely be different. Also,  php --ini | grep -P 'php.ini$' will let you find the main php ini file used. For php-fpm, look for /etc/php* and you should find relevant files with ease. Port 9000 will not work for fastcgi server listening on a socket.